# Frustrated.. lastLocation.getLatitude() will set text but won't initiate a double. Using google api for this one

Tags: java, android, api, google-maps, location

So I've been working literally all day on this and I'm just about to lose my mind. I'm trying to take in coordinates from google's location api in order to get the weather from another api (forcast.io). I've gotten my code to the point that the google api is setting my TextViews perfectly with the correct coordinates... but when I try to assign those coordinates to the value that will be taken and sent as an http link to forcast.io... the values of lat and long are 0.0. I have NO idea what the deal is. I've tried getting the text as a String from my TextViews after they've been initialized in the onConnected() method, I've tried initializing the values as doubles in the onConnected() method... I've done everything I can think of. Here's my code:

```
package com.gardnerwebideas.myweather;

import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.squareup.okhttp.Call;
import com.squareup.okhttp.Callback;
import com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient;
import com.squareup.okhttp.Request;
import com.squareup.okhttp.Response;

import java.io.IOException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {


    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private Location mLastLocation;
    private double mLatitude;
    private double mLongitude;
    private TextView mLatitudeText;
    private TextView mLongitudeText;




//----------------------GOOGLE API BUILD----------------------------
    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();

    }




//--------------------ON CREATE METHOD--------------------------------
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mLatitudeText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.latitudeText);
        mLongitudeText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.longitudeText);

        buildGoogleApiClient();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();




//---------------------CODE FROM ANDROID PROJECT-----------------------
//----------------SETTING UP NETWORK AND WEATHER API-------------------
        String APIKey = "71e3dbfb4ebeb4dc3bcfb07097bb3645";
        String forecastUrl = "https://api.forecast.io/forecast/"
                + APIKey + "/"
                + mLatitude
                + ","
                + mLongitude;
        if (isNetworkAvailable()) {
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(forecastUrl)
                    .build();

            Call call = client.newCall(request);
            call.enqueue(new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {
                    try {
                        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                            Log.v(TAG, response.body().string());
                        } else {
                            alertUserAboutError();
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Exception caught: ", e);
                    }
                }
            });
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Network Unavailable", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "Main UI code is running!");
    }




//------------------------NETWORK METHODS-------------------------------
    private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
        ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = manager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        boolean isAvailable = false;
        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
           isAvailable = true;
        }
        return isAvailable;
    }

    private void alertUserAboutError() {
        AlertDialogFragment dialog = new AlertDialogFragment();
        dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "error_dialogue");
    }




//------------------------GOOGLE API CODE-------------------------------
    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
        if (mLastLocation != null) {
            mLatitudeText.setText(String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLatitude()));
            mLongitudeText.setText(String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLongitude()));
            mLatitude = mLastLocation.getLatitude();
            mLongitude = mLastLocation.getLongitude();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }
}
```

Comment: When OnConnected is called? And when you are sending the request?    I can tell you first you're sending... And onConnected is called after that...

Comment: When should I use the .connect() method? I want to set the variable values to the values returned in the onConnected() method.

Comment: Isn't it obvious that you should call weather api **after** you obtain location?

Comment: Well I thought I was doing that. I call .connect() (and in onConnected() I set the variables to be used in the weather api) before any of the weather api.

Comment: You're wrong...  GoogleApiClient.connect() is asynchronous...

Comment: So could you point me in the right direction perhaps?

Comment: What Selvin is saying is that, you are making the network call to forcast.io before the Google API client (onConnected is called) since the network call is made in onCreate. Try move your network code in onConnected (within the if statement that says mLastLocation != null as a test to see if it works. I am referring to the code labelled //---------------------CODE FROM ANDROID PROJECT-----------------------
//----------------SETTING UP NETWORK AND WEATHER API-------------------

Comment: @johncarter That did the trick. When I moved the weather.io code into the onConnected method it all executed perfectly. Is that bad practice though to put that code in onConnected() as opposed to the onCreate(), or is that just noob talk?

Comment: no, it is not a bad practice ... that's how we are working with asynchronous method with callbacks ... `GoogleApiClient.connect()` may take some time ... `onCreate` is called on main thread ... we don't wana block main thread as it will f** up the users ... so google decide make it asynchronous  ... now the problem is that we don't know when exactly it finishes doing the job(as connect() only starts the job) ... then callbacks come with help ... the `onConnected` it the place when  `GoogleApiClient.connect()` finishes it job ...

Comment: Ok awesome. Well I appreciate you clearing that up for me! I'm not used to asynchronous threads (or really to mobile dev in general), so this will help a lot. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You are missing one critical point: **the geo location information is handled in an asynchronous way**. In your code, this means that the information about your geo position will be available **after** your call to *forecast.io*, and that's the reason why your are always seeing 0 values.

Just update your code in the following way (look at the method `callForecastAPI`):

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.ziby.testing.R;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.squareup.okhttp.Call;
import com.squareup.okhttp.Callback;
import com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient;
import com.squareup.okhttp.Request;
import com.squareup.okhttp.Response;

import java.io.IOException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {


    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private Location mLastLocation;
    private double mLatitude;
    private double mLongitude;
    private TextView mLatitudeText;
    private TextView mLongitudeText;




    //----------------------GOOGLE API BUILD----------------------------
    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();

    }




    //--------------------ON CREATE METHOD--------------------------------
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mLatitudeText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.latitudeText);
        mLongitudeText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.longitudeText);

        buildGoogleApiClient();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        Log.d(TAG, "Main UI code is running!");
    }

    private void callForecastAPI(){
        String APIKey = "71e3dbfb4ebeb4dc3bcfb07097bb3645";
        String forecastUrl = "https://api.forecast.io/forecast/"
                + APIKey + "/"
                + mLatitude
                + ","
                + mLongitude;
        if (isNetworkAvailable()) {
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(forecastUrl)
                    .build();

            Call call = client.newCall(request);
            call.enqueue(new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {
                    try {
                        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                            Log.v(TAG, response.body().string());
                        } else {
                            alertUserAboutError();
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Exception caught: ", e);
                    }
                }
            });
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Network Unavailable", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }



    //------------------------NETWORK METHODS-------------------------------
    private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
        ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = manager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        boolean isAvailable = false;
        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
            isAvailable = true;
        }
        return isAvailable;
    }

    private void alertUserAboutError() {
        AlertDialogFragment dialog = new AlertDialogFragment();
        dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "error_dialogue");
    }




    //------------------------GOOGLE API CODE-------------------------------
    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
        if (mLastLocation != null) {
            mLatitudeText.setText(String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLatitude()));
            mLongitudeText.setText(String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLongitude()));
            mLatitude = mLastLocation.getLatitude();
            mLongitude = mLastLocation.getLongitude();
            callForecastAPI(); //call the forecast API when you get the location
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your two variables

```
private double mLatitude;
private double mLongitude;
```

Are never given any values, so they take the default value of `0`

Will this do the work?

```
String lat = (((TextView) findViewById(R.id.latitudeText)).getText().toString());
mLatitude = Double.parseDouble(lat);
```

Comment: I followed the documentation on the Android Dev site... and they gave me the code to assign the TextViews in the onConnected() method. I figured I'd assign the variables their values there. Now, I'm seeing that the values set in the onConnected() method don't carry over to the rest of the app. How would I assign the coordinate values then?

Comment: @Wilson sorry I really am not an android expert. Wait for an answer. If you do not get it, I'll put a bounty on your question to prove my honesty.

Comment: no problem! I appreciate the eagerness to help! I tried what you suggested and unfortunately it still didn't want to be friendly!